# how to open all links in a file and ignore comments using firefox?

Tags: bash, shell, firefox, command-line

so the file contains data like

```
# entertainment
youtube.com
twitch.tv

# research
google.com
wikipedia.com
...
```

and I would like to pass that file as an argument in a script that would open all lines if they doesn't start with an #. Any clues on how to ?

so far what i have:

```
for Line in $Lines
do
case "# " in $Line start firefox $Line;; esac
done
```

some code that could be useful (?):

```
while read line; do chmod 755 "$line"; done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```sh
grep -e '^[^#]' inputfile.txt | xargs -d '\n' firefox --new-tab
```

`grep -e '^[^#]'`: Will print all lines that don't start with a sharp (comments)

`xargs -d '\n' firefox --new-tab`: Will pass each line that is not blank, as argument to Firefox.

Comment: "`grep -e '^[^#]'`" Why not simply `grep -v '^#'`?  Also, I think `xargs -0` would be more portable than `xargs -d`: `grep -v '^#' inputfile.txt | tr '\n '\000' | xargs -0 firefox --new-tab`.

Comment: Nevermind the first part; now I see that the grep is also used to skip blank lines, nice.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the empty lines and the lines that starts with a `#`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r url; do
  [[ "$url" == \#* || -z "$url" ]] && continue
  firefox --new-tab "$url" &
done < file.txt
```

---

```
awk 'NF && $1!="#"{print "firefox --new-tab", $0, "&"}' file.txt | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Removes both the lines that start with # and empty lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep -Ev "^#|^$") ]]
    then
        firefox --new-tab "$url" &
    fi
done <file.txt
```